# browser not recieving cookies from remote express backend which uses express-session

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, express-session

i'm building an express.js backend app which uses postgress for db with type orm. i'm on login, and decided to use `express-session` with `connect-pg-simple` for session management. My problem is that the frontend does not recieve any cookies.

here are the relevant bits of my app.ts:

```
require("dotenv").config();
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import config from "config";
import { postgresConfig } from "./utils/data-source";

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    const session = require("express-session");
    app.use(
      session({
        // bad practice but well such is life
        store: new (require("connect-pg-simple")(session))({
          conObject: {
            connectionString: `postgresql://${postgresConfig.username}:${postgresConfig.password}@${postgresConfig.host}:${postgresConfig.port}/${postgresConfig.database}`,
          },
        }),
        secret: "1234567890",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
          secure: true,
          path: "/",
          maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        }, // 30 days
      })
    );
```

I've then up a couple routes, one to initialize a session by storing a username in it, and the other to check if there exists a `req.session.username`:

```
    //test session:
    app.get("/startSession", (req, res) => {
      const { username } = req.body;

      // @ts-ignore
      req.session.username = username;

      res.status(200).send("welcome, " + escapeHtml(username));
    });
    app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (!req.session || !req.session.username) {
        res.status(401).send("There is no username in req.session");
      } else {
        res.status(200).send("your session is good, "+ escapeHtml(req.session.username));
      }
    });
...
```

Problem is, when I use postman or insomnia, and make a get request to /startSession then /login, it works as expected, i get response status 200. but when i do that from a browser or any frontend, i get 401. When GETting /startSession, Niether Postman does nor the remote frontend recieve any cookies. I'm using a simple `const resp = fetch("http://localhost:8000/startsession"). What shall I do?

Is there anything I'm missing? If there is a guide on remote API login systems please share it with me. Thanks in advance.